# CUDA callback not being called sometimes

Tags: c, cuda, callback

I am writing some CUDA code. The code is a simulation, so it has to run a number of iterations, and each iteration depends on the neighbour's result. As there is a lot of data, I decided to use streams and tiling.

This is a simplified scheme of the code:

```
sync = (int *)malloc(tiles * tiles * tiles * sizeof(*sync));
memset(sync, 0, tiles * tiles * tiles * sizeof(*sync));

// At the moment tiles = 4
for (i = 0; i < tiles * tiles * tiles; ++i) {
    cudaStreamCreate(&data[i].stream);
    data[i].sync = sync;
    data[i].tiles = tiles;
    data[i].x = i / (tiles * tiles);
    data[i].y = (i / tiles) % tiles;
    data[i].z = i % tiles;

    kernel<<<grid_size, block_size, 0, data[i].stream>>>(/* parameters */);

    cudaStreamAddCallback(data[i].stream, cudaCallback, &data[i], 0);
}

// Synchronization and respawn (now trying just 1 iteration, so no respawn)
for (i = 0; i < tiles * tiles * tiles; ++i) {
    printf("Waiting %d\n", i);
    while (sync[i] != iters) { __sync_synchronize(); }
}
```

The callback:

```
void CUDART_CB cudaCallback(cudaStream_t stream, cudaError_t status, void *data)
{
    struct lifeStreamData *streamData = (struct lifeStreamData *)data;

    __sync_fetch_and_add(&streamData->sync[streamData->x * streamData->tiles * 
                    streamData->tiles + streamData->y * streamData->tiles +
                    streamData->z], 1);

    printf("Callback: done tile %d\n", streamData->x * streamData->tiles * streamData->tiles +
                streamData->y * streamData->tiles + streamData->z);
}
```

But this doesn't work. Only callbacks up to 55 are called. So, the program hangs in "Waiting 56". There are 4 tiles, so there should be 64 callbacks.

Maybe the kernel runs too quick to set up a callback? But why it works on 55 and not on the last 9?

The kernel is correct (at least it doesn't hang) because it was running properly without tiling, and with the parameters, the size and input data can be changed.

I know the code is not optimum nor pretty, but at the moment I'm trying to make this work, so I can optimize from here.

Comment: are you sure that there are not any API errors being reported?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I missed one corner case when resizing the data for the kernel. And it was failing :( I should start by looking at the basic stuff first. Thanks.

Comment: If that is the solution, please add it as an answer to this question to get it off the unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

I missed a corner case when changing the size of the data input to the kernel. That is why it was failing. It is working now.